# MSDEPLOY :Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions' to same type error

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have an MSDEPLOY task within an MSBuild script which i am trying to use to deploy to a remote server.

```
<Target Name="Deploy_v2">
    <ItemGroup>
        <DeploySource Include="package">
            <Path>$(PackagePath)</Path>
        </DeploySource>
        <DeployDestination Include="auto">
            <ComputerName>https://C3PO:8172/msdeploy.axd</ComputerName>
            <UserName>C3PO\developer</UserName>
            <Password>Password123</Password>
            <AuthType>Basic</AuthType>
        </DeployDestination>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="About to deploy!!" />
    <MSDeploy
        Verb="sync"
        Source="@(DeploySource)"
        Destination="@(DeployDestination)" 
        AllowUntrusted="true"
    />
    </Target>
```

When I try to run this I get a very strange message as shown below :

```
MSDEPLOY : error : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentProviderOptions' to type 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.Deployme
ntProviderOptions'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search your harddrive for "MSDeploy.exe"....and see how many different versions you have.

Then experiment with setting the "ToolPath"

```
<MSDeploy
    ToolPath="C:\OneOfTheFoldersWithMsDeployExeInIt" 
    Verb="sync"
    Source="@(DeploySource)"
    Destination="@(DeployDestination)" 
    AllowUntrusted="true"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks again, this has fixed it. I had un-installed Web Deploy 2.0 and just left Web Deploy 3.5 but I still had two versions of MSDeploy.exe on my system. Added "ToolPath="C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3" and problem solved. Well, now I have another weird issue but will open that in a new thread, thanks again!

Comment: The thing about alot of custom MSBuild tasks, is that they just 'wrap up nice' some command line call.  So somewhere (in the code of the custo MsBuild Task), a CommandLine.Exe is being called with arguments.  And it will default to some common ToolPath.  Just a little rule-of-thumb.